# multiple datasets, percentage histogram, position="dodge" doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two datasets, they have the same variables, but the samples sizes are very different. I want two histograms with percentage (instead of count) together side by side using `position = "dodge"`. Below is the code I used:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = df1, aes(x=var1, fill="sample1", y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                 binwidth=5, colour ="gray45") +
  geom_histogram(data=df2, aes(x=var1, fill="sample2", y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth=5,
                 colour ="gray45", position=position_dodge(5)) +
  scale_y_continuous (labels = scales::percent)
```

The figure I got looks like this.
What did I wrong...??

[image: The figure I got]

Comment: Please provide sample data. Paste in a sample of your data using `dput()`.

Comment: You need to have your data in a single data frame with a new column that you use as the fill column. This new column will have one label for the first data frame's data and another for the second data frame's data.